# how to convert a JSON code to map

Tags: json, dictionary

use the org.json.jar

I know convert a JSON code to JSONObject

```
JSONObject fieldsJson = new JSONObject("{\"a\":\"b\"}"); 
String value= fieldsJson.getString("a");
```

But how to convert a JSON code to map

Comment: In which programming language? JavaScript? Java? Just about every language has support for JSON these days.

Answer (score 0):

`String str = "{\"age\":\"23\",\"name\":\"ganlu\"}";
    JSONObject jobj = JSONObject.fromObject(str);
    Map<String,String> tmpMap = (Map) JSONObject.toBean(jobj,Map.class);
    Set<String> keys = tmpMap.keySet();
    for(String key : keys){
      System.out.println(key+":"+tmpMap.get(key));
    }`

May this will help you.